# How to get/parse the "target" of a redirect in (ba)sh command

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, redirect, posix

I have to run a binary through a simulator, but the binary is part of a huge and complicated benchmarking suite. So what on the normal system would look like this:

```
# First form
./binary -long=list -of=args <input.txt >std.out 2>std.err
```

needs to look like this:

```
# second form
simulator -c ./binary -o "-long=list -of=args" -i input.txt --output=std.out --errout=std.err
```

The benchmarking suit is passing around the command, i.e. the binary with all the stuff after it (args and redirects) in (bash) variables e.g. `$CMD="./binary -long=list -of=args <input.txt >std.out 2>std.err"`, and I would need to find out what are the targets of all the redirects (i.e. `intpu.txt`, `std.out` and `std.err` in the example) so I can convert the command in the first form to the command in the second form).

So is there a way to, for example, tell bash to take the command `$CMD`, which contains the binary, the args and the redirects, and parse it, and then return, say, what was the input redirect (i.e. `input.txt`), or one of the other redirects (`std.out` or `std.err`)?

Without manually doing the parsing of course...

Something like this:

```
$ CMD="./binary -long=list -of=args <input.txt >std.out 2>std.err"
$ bash -secret_option_to_parse_redirect_target=input "$CMD"
intpu.txt
$ bash -secret_option_to_parse_redirect_target=output "$CMD"
std.out
$ bash -secret_option_to_parse_redirect_target=error "$CMD"
std.err
```

Comment: Redirections are already applied before the command they're run on has started. Constantly, they aren't passed to that command; only the file descriptors resulting from their execution are available.

Comment: That said, if your OS is Linux, you can use `/proc/self/fd` to inspect the file descriptors you were passed.

Comment: The harder part, then, is if you want the simulator's own output and logs to go to the parent process's original pre-redirection stdout and stderr, because the child doesn't inherit them. You can try to pull those out of procfs too, of course, but that's prone to race conditions -- where the parent process's stdout and stderr point not may not be where those descriptors pointed back when it first spawned the child.

Comment: Updated the question, hope it's more clear now. I don't want the do any redirection. I want basically to parse a bash command (command = the string you enter in the command line, a line of a bash script).

Comment: There's no bash-builtin way to do that. The most common approaches used involve either xargs or the Python `shlex` library, but they don't cover redirects.

Comment: Passing a shell command as a single string is already fragile. I would adapt whatever generates `CMD` to produce something more structured.

Comment: Yes, that's a big pain in the neck... we're messing around with Spec benchmarks, and they have a huge mess of a "benchmarking harness" of bash scripts which are a pain to change :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust your `cmd` to parse to a single simple command, you can use `eval` to add a wrapper around it that reads the command line and active redirections. See this code running at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/GrouchyHelplessInformationtechnology#main.sh

Note that this requires an operating system with a `/proc/*/fd` interface compatible with that provided by Linux.

```
read_fd() {
  local fd_num dest_var fd_dest default_val bash_pid=$BASHPID
  fd_num=$1; dest_var=$2; default_val=${3:-"/proc/self/fd/$fd_num"}
  printf -v "$dest_var" %s "$default_val"
  [[ -e /proc/$bash_pid/fd/$fd_nume ]] || return
  fd_dest="$(readlink "/proc/$bash_pid/fd/$fd_num")" || return
  [[ -e $fd_dest ]] || return
  printf -v "$dest_var" %s "$fd_dest"
}

parse_cmd() {
  read_fd 0 stdin_src
  read_fd 1 stdout_dest
  read_fd 2 stderr_dest
  argv_dest=( "$@" )
}
```

...used as:

```
# all-caps variable names are reserved; do not use them in your own code
cmd="./binary -long=list -of=args <input.txt >std.out 2>std.err"

# inputs need to exist for redirections to work
touch input.txt

eval "parse_cmd $cmd"
echo "stdout destination is $stdout_dest"
echo "stderr destination is $stderr_dest"
echo "stdin source is $stdin_src"
echo "argument list follows, one per line:"
printf ' - %q\n' "${argv_dest[@]}"
echo
echo "to run this, you could use:"
echo "${argv_dest[*]@Q} <$stdin_src >$stdout_dest 2>$stderr_dest"
```

Comment: Wait, will this work if there is e.g. no output redirection?

Comment: @EmilVatai, it uses `stdout_dest=/proc/self/fd/1` in that case, which is exactly the same as "whatever our stdout is right now", which is the no-redirection case.

Comment: @EmilVatai, alternately, if you wanted to change the code to make it leave `stdout_dest` default in that case, you could use something like `${stdout_dest:+-o "$stdout_dest"}` in the command line you're forming from this -- only inserting `-o` if `stdout_dest` is non-empty

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to work. If I remove the `>std.out` and `>std.err` part, the `local -n` says invalid option...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `local -n` is passed `$1`; its value has nothing to do with any redirections. I'd need to see the failure to believe it.

Comment: Ahhh... wait... working on this with a colleague... His running the stuff... might be screw up on our part... hold on!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238321/discussion-between-emil-vatai-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: Ok. Almost works. You need a `-f` instead of `-e` in the second test of `read_fd()`!

Comment: I don't agree that that's always correct. Stdin and stdout can legitimately go to things that aren't regular files (think of named FIFOs or character devices for a few examples). Can you describe the specific case where `-e` has unwanted behavior?

Comment: yeah, it always gives the pseudo terminal `/dev/pts/0` as the result if one of the redirects is missing... which is technically correct of course, but not desired. Of course I totally get your argument for non regular files.

Comment: If you want to special-case `/dev/pts/*`, I'd make it explicit, instead of making _all_ character devices be ignored. That is: `[[ $fd_dest = /dev/pts/* ]] && return 1`, if that's what you want to do.